# How to inject ApplicationContextProvider for tests using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

While running the tests using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext() throws error saying ApplicationContext is null. can someone help on this?

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
  @PrepareForTest({SampleCofig.class})
  public class ConfigTest extends IntegrationTest {

    
   public void GetConfigTest(){ 
   Configuration config = SampleConfig.getConfig();
   }

  }


  @WebAppConfiguration
  @ContextConfiguration(classes = {Config.class})
  public abstract class IntegrationTest {

    @Configuration
    static class Config {

      @Bean(name = "StreamEngineA")
      @Autowired
      public StreamEngineA execute() {
        return new getEngineA();
      }

      @Bean(name = "StreamEngineB")
      @Autowired
      public StreamEngineB execute1() {
        return new getEngineB();
      }

    }


    public class SampleConfig {


      public Config getConfig() {
        Configuration config = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext()
            .getBean(Configuration.class);

      }

    }
```

Comment: Please provide piece of code, otherwise it is impossible to guess..

Comment: @borino thank you for the response, please find the code snippet

Comment: Did you try `@Autowired ApplicationContext appContext;` instead of using 'ApplicationContextProvider'. I see you trying to get config, it is more like spring way - `@Autowired Configuration configuration`